# Proof that $P(A \mid C) = 1$ implies $P(A \mid B∩ C) = 1$

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

This isn't homework. I'm reading Probabilistic Graphical Models by Koller et al.$\space$, and an easy problem in chapter $3$ made me think of a more general problem (which I'm now stuck on). I have everything in place except for this:

Let $P(B \cap C) \neq 0$. Then $P(A \space|\space B ∩ C) = 1$ if $P(A \mid C) = 1$. It's intuitively obvious, but I haven't been able to formally prove it. I get

$$P(A \mid B∩C) = \dfrac{P(A∩B∩C)}{P(B∩C)} = \dfrac{P(C) P(A\mid C) P(B\mid A∩C)}{P(B∩C)} = \dfrac{P(B\mid A∩C)}{P(B|C)}$$

I don't see why that ratio on the right hand side is $1$. Is it? What am I not seeing?

Comment: What's $B,C$? Is it $B \cap C$ or $B \cup C$?

Comment: I think something about the probability space has to be assumed.  E.g. what prevents $P(B\cap C) = 0$ ?

Comment: Sorry, $B,C$ meant $B \cap C$. Also, I should have said that this is for the case where $P(B \cap C) \neq 0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume that $\mathbb P(\ \mid C)$ and $\mathbb P(\ \mid B\cap C)$ both exist, that is, that 
$$\mathbb P(B\cap C)\ne0.
$$
Then note that $\mathbb P(A\mid C)=1$ if and only if $\mathbb P(A\cap C)=\mathbb P(C)$ if and only if $\mathbb P(C\setminus A)=0$. Likewise, $\mathbb P(A\mid B\cap C)=1$ if and only if $\mathbb P((B\cap C)\setminus A)=0$. But $(B\cap C)\setminus A\subseteq C\setminus A$, hence the latter implies the former, that is,
$$
\mathbb P(A\mid C)=1\implies \mathbb P(A\mid B\cap C)=1.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $P(B\cap C)>0$ (hence $P(C)>0$), we have

- $P(A\mid C)=1\iff P(\bar A\mid C)=0\iff P(\bar A\cap C)=0$
- and similarly, $P(A\mid B\cap C)=1\iff P(\bar A\cap B\cap C)=0$.

Since $P(\bar A\cap B\cap C)\le P(\bar A\cap C)$, the result follows.

Answer (score 0):

Mmmm ... I don't think it's obvious, really.  In fact, I think there are a couple of ready counter-examples.

First, let's say $A\cap C =C$.  That is, anytime we have $C$, we have $A$.  But let's say $B\cap A=\emptyset$.  Then, $P(A|C)=1$.  But $P(A|B)=0$, and therefore $P(A|B,C)=0$.

Also, we could say $A\cap C =C$ and $A\cap B=B$, but $B\cap C=\emptyset$.  Then the probability of *anything* given $B$ and $C$ is zero.

AFAICT, your first statement implies the second only in the special case where 1) $A\cap C =C$ and 2) $A\cap (B\cap C) = B\cap C$.

Comment: If you have $A∩C=C$ then $A∩(B∩C)=B∩C$ would follow automatically.

Comment: Granted.  I was just trying to provide the bare minimum for answering the question.

Comment: All your counterexamples have $P(B\cap C)=0$.  If that is the case then $P(A \mid B\cap C)$ is not well-defined for any $A$

Answer (score 0):

For any three events $A,B,C$ ,$P(A∩B∩C)=P[(A ∩C) ∩(B∩C)]=P(A ∩C)+ P(B∩C)-P[(A ∩C) ∪(B∩C)]$$=P(A ∩C)+ P(B∩C)-P[(A∪B)∩C]$$=P(A ∩C)+ P(B∩C)-P(C)-P(A∪B)+P(A∪B∪C)$ 
. Now  $\space$$\space$

$(A ∪ B) ⊆ (A ∪ B ∪C)$

$\implies$ $ P(A∪B) ≤ P(A∪B∪C)$

$\implies$$P(A ∩C)+ P(B∩C)-P(C)$

$\space$ $\space$ $\space$ $\space$$≤P(A ∩C)+ P(B∩C)-P(C)-P(A∪B)+P(A∪B∪C)$

$\implies$$P(A ∩C)+ P(B∩C)-P(C)≤P(A∩B∩C)$....(i) Moreover,

$(A∩B∩C)⊆(B∩C)$$\implies$$P(A∩B∩C)≤P(B∩C)$ , so this along with (i) gives,

$P(A ∩C)-P(C)≤P(A∩B∩C)-P(B∩C)≤0$  . Hence ,

$P(A|C)=1 \implies P(A ∩C)=P(C) \implies$$0≤P(A∩B∩C)-P(B∩C)≤0$

$\implies  P(A∩B∩C)=P(B∩C)$$\implies P\big(A|(B∩C)\big)=1$

Comment: Note that $A\cap C\subset C$ does not imply that $P(A\cap C)\lt P(C)$, only that $P(A\cap C)\leqslant P(C)$, even assuming that $A\cap C\ne C$.

Answer (score -1):

$\mathbb{P}\{A|C\}=1$ implies $\mathbb{P}\{A,C\}=\mathbb{P}\{C\}$, which implies $A\subset C$. Therefore $\mathbb{P}\{A|B,C\}=1$.

Comment: $P(A,C)=P(C)$ does not imply that $A\subset C$.