# Proving $P(A\mid B,C)=1$ given $P(A\mid B)=1$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

I'm trying to prove the following statement formally: if $P(A\mid B)=1$, then $P(A\mid B,C)=1$.

I can see why logically speaking the statement is correct but I'm lacking a formal argument, using perhaps some formulas.

I hope the description is clear enough.
I am happy to give more details if needed.

Comment: I suspect you need $P(B,C)>0$.  Could you edit your question to include what you have tried?

Comment: Usually we define $P(A|B)$ for events $A,B$. How di you define $P(A|B,C)$? I assume it is $P(A|B\cap C)$, is that right?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in answering this comment! I saw that the question was already been solved, and I did not check mine anymore. Anyway, yes you need $P(B,C)>0$, and for $P(A|B \cap C)$ there's a formula I used that is $P(A|B \cap C)=\frac{P(A \cap B \cap C)}{p(B \cap C)}$.

Comment: In case you are wondering, here is where I was redirected https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376607/proof-that-pa-mid-c-1-implies-pa-mid-b%e2%88%a9-c-1